# Style JSX in NextJS project does not work with external (antd) components

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, antd, react-component

I'm looking to use Style JSX in a Next JS app for customizing AntD components. Specifically, I want to customize the sidebar appearance (by customizing AntD's Sider component **with Style JSX**). I have the following code:

```
   <>
        <Sider collapsible collapsed={collapsed}
        onCollapse={onCollapse} id='left-sidebar'
        >
            <div id='components-layout-demo-side'/>
            <Menu theme="light" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']} mode="inline">
                <Menu.Item key="1" icon={<PieChartOutlined />} >Option 1</Menu.Item>
                    
                <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<DesktopOutlined />} >Option 2</Menu.Item>
                        
            </Menu>
            // style jsx here
        </Sider>
        // or style jsx here
   </>
```

Among many customizations, imagine I want to change the background color to something else. I have tried the following:

1. Try referencing by id like this:

```
    <style jsx>{`
        #left-sidebar { background-color: #fff }
    `}</style>
```

2. Tried the above by referencing the resulting html element, i.e. aside (along with the resulting classname ant-layout-sider).
3. Used [css.resolve](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#the-resolve-tag) as mentioned in the docs to no avail as suggested by Next JS docs (regarding external components).

No matter what, the browser does not get the styles at all (checked thoroughly through inspect element).

I tried experimenting in other ways as well, but with style jsx it does not seem to work unless I make the style global. The styles are applied when I apply this to a global.css file or when I use css-modules for components. However, I can not get it to work even after following NextJs docs.

My guess is the framework strips the css styles even before the actual elements are generated. My question is, is this entirely not possible, or am I missing something? The above example is taken from [Antd Layouts Sider](https://ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-side).

Answer (score 0):

You may be just making a simple mistake -  in what you've pasted:

```
<style jsx>
        #left-sidebar { background-color: #fff }
</style>
```

you're missing {` `}

```
<style jsx>{`
        #left-sidebar { background-color: #fff }
`}</style>
```

[Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/blog/styling-next-with-styled-jsx)

Comment: Hi, you're right it should be {``} but that's not the problem. I wrote the code here so hence forgot them.

Comment: Have you tried !important? it may be a problem that your styles are being overwritten by the default styles of this Sider component hence your styles don't work

Comment: I have. They are not even being generated in the browser (checked all styles against the id/class in inspect element).